# Rails Random Number Between 0 and 3 always 0 or 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am using random numbers to try to call a random partial.  I have the `erb`:

```
<% @random_partial = 'man_tests/test' + [*0..3].sample %>
<%= render partial: @random_partial %>
```

But I have also tried `rand(0..3).round.to_s` and the same thing happens: No matter how many times I click the button, it shows me `_test0.html.erb` or `_test1.html.erb`.  I have tried enough that it would be statistically crazy if it was by chance that I only ever got these two.  I even tried switching the content from `_test0` and `_test3` to see if it was somehow causing the problem and I still only got the ones named 0 and 1.

Can anyone help me figure out what's causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [this fiddle out](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/48d59/2):

```
print 'man_tests/test' + Random.rand(100).to_s
```

Also, make sure you are not getting served some cached page by your server.

Comment: Still just alternating randomly between 0 and 1.

Comment: Do you really need the floating point rounding? According to [Random doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Random.html), `rand(3)` would give you random integers between 0 and 2.

Comment: I tried that as well.  I now have 5 options (tests 0-4) to decrease the odds of the same one being picked twice and it still only picks 0 or 1.

Comment: I know!  I've done a repl.it and gotten a working model with my exact same code, but it DEFINITELY doesn't work on the site.  I also did a `find all` search in my app and that's the only place `rand` is used, so I know I'm not just changing the wrong method.

Comment: I now have 6 options (1-5) and I changed my code to `<% rng = Random.new %>
  <% @random_partial = 'man_tests/test' + rng.rand(6).round.to_s %>
  <%= render partial: @random_partial %>` and it still only selects 0 and 1!

Comment: Are you caching the page? Try clearing your browser or using private-mode.

Comment: Tried both incognito and clearing the cache.  Still just 0 and 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124951/discussion-between-pedro-baracho-and-liz).